# Unable to use SET OF record or return table(col1,[col2]) return type in pgadmin 4 version 2?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions, pgadmin-4

Basically i want to split the string based on the delimiter for example :- 
"this,is,foo" should return this is foo i.e; without the comma into separate records .
i am trying to use pgadmin 4 version 2.

this is my sample code below that i want in function dialog :-

```
create or replace function STRING_SPLIT(str text,delimiter character)
return SET OF record;
as 
begin
return QUERY SELECT trim(a)
FROM unnest(string_to_array('john,smith,jones', ',')) AS a; //str, delim
end
```

i am basically trying to insert the expanded row array into set of records.
i tried creating table and return it in the return statement  but could not specify the column name in function dialog of pgadmin also i could not find "set of record" return type in the same dialog box?

can anyone help?

Comment: Unrelated, but: why write a function that is already available in Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases, using `returns table()` is the better solution.

```
create or replace function STRING_SPLIT(str text,delimiter character)
   return table(word text) --<< no ; here!!
as 
$$ --<< you need quotes around the body
  SELECT trim(a) as word
  FROM unnest(string_to_array(text, delimiter)) AS t(a);
$$
language sql; --<< no PL/pgSQL required, SQL is enough
```

---

If you do want to use `setof record` then you always have to specify the column names when *using* the function:

```
create or replace function STRING_SPLIT(str text,delimiter character)
   return setof record
as 
$$ --<< you need quotes around the body
  SELECT trim(a) as word
  FROM unnest(string_to_array(text, delimiter)) AS t(a);
$$
language sql; --<< no PL/pgSQL required, SQL is enough
```

Then:

```
select *
from string_split('foo,bar',',') as t(word);
```

---

However, Postgres already has a built-in function for this:

```
select *
from regexp_split_to_table('foo,bar',',') as t(word);
```

Comment: Thank you , I appreciate your answer , however i could not see the  **return table/set of** option in the function dialog under the definition tab and return type Drop down list in it. Any idea?

Comment: @abdulgaffar: no idea, I don't use pgAdmin. All you need is to just run those SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Though this post is older, but needs to post an answer here. So it will help people like me. As I was looking for the same and found the answer.
in pgAdmin4 'setof' is not present in the return type. While creating function in pgAdmin using create function window, you need to select record as a return type.
[Then click on the options and set "Returns a set?" to "Yes". like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSISX.png)

Then it will automatically take setof record as a return type and will show in code in sql viwer, but not in return type selected.

[Then it will automatically take setof record as a return type and will show in code in sql viwer, but not in return type selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDesf.png)

Comment: The real answer is: don't use a GUI to write code. Use a text editor to write code.

Comment: Yes. If we use query tool to create function for database then it's more easy to add return types and parameters without any issues than using create function gui. I only tried after you said. I am a beginner to pgAdmin and sql so had no clear picture about using tools.